# Extract subgraph in neo4j using cypher query

Tags: java, neo4j

I'm using neo4j 3.1 with java 8 and I want to extract a connected subgraph as to store it as a test database. 
Is it possible to do it and how? 
How to do it with the clause Return which returns the output. So, I had to create new nodes and relations or just export the subgraph and put it in a new database.

How can I extract a connected subgraph since I have a disconnected graph.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two parts to this...getting the connected subgraph, and then finding a means to export.

[APOC Procedures](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/) seems like it can cover both of these. The approach in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41863104/92359) using the path expander should get you all the nodes in the connected subgraph (if the relationship type doesn't matter, leave off the relationshipFilter parameter).

The next step is to get all relationships between all of those nodes. APOC's apoc.algo.cover() function in the [graph algorithms section](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_graph_algorithms_work_in_progress) should accomplish this.

Something like this (assuming this is after the subgraph query, and `subgraphNode` is in scope for the column of distinct subgraph nodes):

```
...
WITH COLLECT(subgraphNode) as subgraph, COLLECT(id(subgraphNode)) as ids
CALL apoc.algo.cover(ids) YIELD rel
WITH subgraph, COLLECT(rel) as rels
...
```

Now that you have the collections of both the nodes and relationships in the subgraph, you can export them.

APOC Procedures offers [several means of exporting](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_export_import), from CSV to CypherScript. You should be able to find an option that works for you.

Comment: I installed APOC and I'm trying to test an example to undersant how it works since it is the first time that I used it
Thank you

Comment: I tried this and it works perfectly. However, I would like to know the meaning of this parameter: MaxLevel and uniqueness:"Node_global"?

Comment: Sure. `maxLevel` and `minLevel` define the minimum and maximum number of traversals as we traverse. Paths should only be returned where the path length (number of traversals from the starting node) are between the levels given...

Comment: [Uniqueness](http://neo4j.com/docs/java-reference/current/javadocs/org/neo4j/graphdb/traversal/Uniqueness.html) is a Neo4j enum defining what uniqueness constraints/behavior to use during the traversals used for path expansion. `NODE_GLOBAL` means that a node cannot be traversed more than once. Only one path ending to that node will be returned. The resulting nodes and edges with NODE_GLOBAL (and no minLevel) will be a [spanning tree](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/data_structures_algorithms/spanning_tree.htm). This approach lets us find nodes in a subgraph fast without unnecessary traversals.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the `neo4j-shell` to extract the result of a query to a file and use this same file to re-import it in the neo4j database :

```
ikwattro@graphaware-team ~/d/_/310> ./bin/neo4j-shell -c 'dump MATCH (n:Product)-[r*2]->(x) RETURN n, r, x;' > result.cypher
```

check the file

```
ikwattro@graphaware-team ~/d/_/310> cat result.cypher
begin
commit
begin
create (_1:`Product` {`id`:"product123"})
create (_2:`ProductInformation` {`id`:"product123EXCEL"})
create (_3:`ProductInformationElement` {`id`:"product123EXCELtitle", `key`:"title", `value`:"Original Title"})
create (_5:`ProductInformationElement` {`id`:"product123EXCELproduct_type", `key`:"product_type", `value`:"casual_bag"})
create (_1)-[:`PRODUCT_INFORMATION`]->(_2)
create (_2)-[:`INFORMATION_ELEMENT`]->(_3)
create (_2)-[:`INFORMATION_ELEMENT`]->(_5)
;
commit
```

Use this file for feeding another neo4j :

```
ikwattro@graphaware-team ~/d/_/310> ./bin/neo4j-shell -file result.cypher
Transaction started
Transaction committed
Transaction started
+-------------------+
| No data returned. |
+-------------------+
Nodes created: 4
Relationships created: 3
Properties set: 8
Labels added: 4
52 ms
Transaction committed
```

Comment: I tried this but my problem that I have two installations of neo4j:
- I installed neo4j .exe and there I created my database with py2neo but this one doesn't contain neo4j-shell
- I installed neo4j .zip but It doesn't contains my database.

So, how can I settle this?

Comment: argh cannot really help, didn't used Windows since dinosaurs disappeared from earth :/

Comment: I tried this but I got an error :
`ERROR (-v for expanded information):
        Connection refused`
I don't see what's the problem

Comment: I tried this but I got this in the file :
`Welcome to the Neo4j Shell! Enter 'help' for a list of commands. Please note that neo4j-shell is deprecated and to be replaced by cypher-shell.
NOTE: Remote Neo4j graph database service 'shell' at port 1337

neo4j-sh (?)$ `